# Ionic 2 Send a Push Notification In The Client Side

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

i have a question.

I did the installation of Ionic 2 push notification with FCM and it works.

But ı want to send notification when I press the button in the application(client side) I made .

Can this be done?

app.module

```
 const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'myappid'
  },  'push': {
    'sender_id': 'mysnderid',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        badge': true,
         'sound': true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Let your application send a message to the server so it will broadcast a push notification. If you want to push a notification to your own device you can use local notifications in ionic native

Comment: Hi , im trying to API endpoint to create push notifications.